# swap items 2 listview xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

so basically i have to move 1 item from 1 listview to another with the location being the one you tapped using xamarin.forms

the idea i got right now is to swap their values...

the problem is however i dont understand understand xamarin at all 
if youre asking why im working with xamarin then instead of something easier the answer is my teammates they wanted xamarin so im screwed

i tried doing the docs and tutorials about item tapped and stuff like that but i think im checking in the wrong direction

so if anyone could point me to what i actually need to study and do to get code working like that

id appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning with Xamarin can be tricky sometimes, but I'm sure you'll get the hang of it after some tutorials.

I believe the following should help you out, assuming you're using XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="Test.MultiListView">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView x:Name="ListOneListView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOne}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Add" Clicked="Add" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Remove" Clicked="Remove" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ListTwoListView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding ListTwo}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And the CodeBehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MultiListView : ContentPage
    {
        MultiListViewVM vm;

        public MultiListView()
        {
            vm = new MultiListViewVM();
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = vm;
        }

        public void Add(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(ListOneListView.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            vm.ListTwo.Add(ListOneListView.SelectedItem as ListItem);
            vm.ListOne.Remove(ListOneListView.SelectedItem as ListItem);

            ListOneListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        public void Remove(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(ListTwoListView.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            vm.ListOne.Add(ListTwoListView.SelectedItem as ListItem);
            vm.ListTwo.Remove(ListTwoListView.SelectedItem as ListItem);

            ListTwoListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }

    class MultiListViewVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ListItem> listOne;
        private ObservableCollection<ListItem> listTwo;

        public ObservableCollection<ListItem> ListOne
        {
            get
            {
                return listOne;
            }
            set
            {
                listOne = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ListOne");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ListItem> ListTwo
        {
            get
            {
                return listTwo;
            }
            set
            {
                listTwo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ListTwo");
            }
        }

        public MultiListViewVM()
        {
            ListOne = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>();
            ListTwo = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>();

            SetupData();
        }

        private void SetupData()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                var dayName = new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.GetDayName((DayOfWeek)i);
                var item = new ListItem(dayName, "Description");
                ListOne.Add(item);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    class ListItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ListItem(string title, string description)
        {
            Title = title;
            Description = description;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is easy to understand.

Comment: i think i understand it ... but i need to target the list location too ... which i can do by adding a thrid hidden list i think ... thx a lot now just to figure out how to actually put it on the slected spot...